# Is there a standard for describing information about Java Beans (Bean Introspections)

Tags: java, standards, industry-standard

In many situations we need access to meta information about Java Beans. The Java Reflection API itsself does not work for projects were performance matters so the bigger Frameworks like Spring or Micronaut made their own stuff but also Java introduced something.

Currently i am aiming to write a library for serializing Java Beans in a special way (like rowsets in SQL). However i'd like this code to be able to handle all the above Bean Informations. So i was wondering if there is a de facto standard (like JSR330 for DI Annoations) for representing Reflection / Introspection Information about a java Bean. If not, what would might be the way to start such a standardization process.

Micronaut uses BeanIntrospection
Spring uses CachedIntrospectionResults
and Java8+ has this Beanintrospector and BeanInfo stuff i never saw outside of annotation processors

Comment: What meta information do you need and why?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about your need, but i think this could help you: https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/ Take special attention on BeanInfo interface.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the JavaBeans you are thinking of are really JavaBeans™.  What people now call "JavaBeans" (for at least a decade) are really just degenerate objects.  JavaBeans™ never really worked out as intended and they were always built around reflection.